# Eight identical spheres fit inside a cube

Tags: mathematics, geometry, three-dimensional

Eight identical spheres fit inside a cube with side length of 1 unit. What is the largest possible radius for a sphere which would fit between those 8 spheres (in the center)?  There are no gaps between spheres as well as between each sphere and the face of the cube.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

Comment: Pretty sure its (sqrt3-1)/2

Comment: @Beastly You changed your comment after seeing my answer :-P

Comment: @randal'thor realised I had added two radii instead of two diameters. Don't think its /2sqrt3 though, just /2

Comment: @Beastly Are you talking about the diagonal or the side-length of the small cube?

Comment: @randal'thor no. I'm thinking the diagonal (sqrt) has two spheres in it (-1) so the diameter is sqrt3-1 and the radius is half that. I agree up till your last point in your answer

Comment: @Beastly Actually you're right: it's the side-length and not the diagonal which should fit between opposite squares. Edited my answer to fix this after your and humn's comments.

Comment: @randal'thor hehe a 14 year old beat you at maths :P

Comment: This is not so much a puzzle as a mathematical question. Vote to close.

Comment: @wbogacz I disagree. It's not trivial to solve, and some geometric insight is needed, plus the "aha" which is in the first spoilertag in my answer.

Comment: @rand, needing geometric insight doesn't take it out of the realm of standard geometry textbook problem and into the realm of puzzles.

Comment: @rand where do we draw the line though? We can totally post any AIME-style question and it would always have some form of an "Aha!" moment...  Exactly how much "Aha!" is needed to consider a math question a good puzzle?

Comment: @green "Aha" is one of the criteria mentioned in [the policy](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2784/5373) on maths problems vs maths puzzles.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mceaM2_zQd8 so unless you came up with this puzzle yourself, you must credit where you found it; i.e., include sources of the puzzle and/or motivation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The large cube has side-length $1$.
- Two touching spheres stretch exactly across the length of the cube, so each of the spheres has diameter $\frac{1}{2}$ and radius $\frac{1}{4}$.
- > The largest possible small cube which can fit between the spheres is such that each of its faces is tangential to one of the spheres.
- Thus the side-length of the small cube must fit exactly between two diagonally opposite spheres. By symmetry of the spheres, the distance between the centres of these two spheres is exactly half the diagonal of the large cube. So the side-length of the small cube is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$.

To visualise this, it might help to consider the 3D analogue of the following not-very-good 2D picture:

> [image: square within cubes within square]

EDIT: after the OP changed from a small cube to a small sphere, my answer remains the same except that instead of the side-length of the small cube, we should consider the diameter of the small sphere; this length should still be $\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}$.

EDIT 2: actually my answer for a small cube was invalid (touching all eight spheres would make it an octahedron, not a cube), but the version with a small sphere is still fine.

Comment: He's edited it to make it a sphere not a cube in the middle

Comment: @Beastly Yep, just saw, and fixed my answer accordingly. (Fortunately not much had to change.)

Comment: The funny thing was I didn't read the question properly and thought it was a sphere from the start, even when I was arguing my point with you. Lucky for me it works for both! :P

Comment: I'd hate to see the cube solution be forgotten. It is more subtle. Please leave it on display, rand al'thor, or create a new puzzle for it.

Comment: @Beastly Yeah, I did wonder why you were talking about "diameter" and "radius" instead of side-length :-P

Comment: @humn Definitely. I was planning to leave the answer in its current state: first the solution for a cube, and then the final paragraph at the bottom to explain how this changes for a sphere. (As in fact the OP has done with their question: it still says "cube" until the final line.)

Comment: Ah yes, the famous eight-faced cube. Less flippantly: unless I'm missing something, the polyhedron in the middle with faces tangent to all the spheres is an octahedron, not a cube. This doesn't invalidate the solution to the modified puzzle with a sphere in the middle, of course.